# How to filter a table row using JQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The scenario is , there is a table which contains dropdown selectbox in its 'td'. And, there is a dropdown selectbox outside which when selected filters table rows when values match in table's selectbox.

Here when selectFilter value is changed, it checks this value matches with the already 'selected' value in table.
Here some rows are hidden, so we need to filter the rows that is only visible .
Here is fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/manzer/8q7owxj5/

```
     <html>
        <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
        </head>
        <body>
        <select id="selectFilter">
    <option>Select...</option>
    <option value="cat">Cats</option>
    <option value="dog">Dogs</option>
    <option value="birds">Birds</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>

<table id="animals">
<tbody>
    <tr >
        <td>
        <select>
        <option value="dog">Dog<</option>
        <option value="cat" selected>Cat</option>
        <option value="birds">Birds<</option>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
      <tr style="display:none;">
        <td>
        <select>
        <option value="dog">Dog<</option>
        <option value="cat" selected>Cat</option>
        <option value="birds">Birds<</option>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr >
          <td>
        <select>
        <option value="dog">Dog</option>
        <option value="cat">Cat</option>
        <option value="birds" selected>Birds</option>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>

       <tr style="display:none;">
        <td>
        <select>
        <option value="dog">Dog<</option>
        <option value="cat" selected>Cat</option>
        <option value="birds">Birds<</option>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
           <td>
        <select>
        <option value="dog">Dog</option>
        <option value="cat" selected>Cat</option>
        <option value="birds">Birds</option>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>

          <tr style="display:none;">
        <td>
        <select>
        <option value="dog">Dog<</option>
        <option value="cat" selected>Cat</option>
        <option value="birds">Birds<</option>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>
        <select>
        <option value="dog" selected>Dog</option>
        <option value="cat">Cat</option>
        <option value="birds">Birds</option>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br>

        <script>
               //here when selectFilter value is changed, it checks 
            //this value matches with the already 'selected' value in table.
            //here some rows are hidden, so we need to filter the rows that is //only visible .
           //we need to filter visible rows when value matches from dropdown
           $('#selectFilter').change(function() {
            alert("hi")

            });

        </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are exactly asking here

Comment: In first row,"cat" is selected,likewise in third row "birds" is selected,in fifth row again cat is selected in "td>select" and so on. So, when, id="selectFilter" is changed, then search this value in td which have this selected value and show the row and rest row should hide.

Comment: You should put this in the body of the question using the Edit functionality.

Comment: Note: some rows which are having display:none; should not take part in filtering. In other words, any row that is visible, filter should apply on that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Here is working code. However, I have to remove/edit the missing/extra html (tr> tags in your HTML

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#selectFilter').change(function () {
            var selectedVal = $("#selectFilter option:selected").val();
            alert(selectedVal);
            $('#animals tbody tr:visible').each(function () {
                var val = $(this).find('select option:selected').text();
                if (selectedVal.toLowerCase() != val.toLowerCase()) {
                    $(this).hide();

                }
                else {
                    $(this).show();
                }

            });


        });
    });
```

Comment: Sorry,its not working, please have a look at my fiddle.

Comment: i have correct issues with your html tags   https://jsfiddle.net/nb6kvus2/

Comment: when selecting dogs after cat, dog is not filtered nor birds.

Comment: Selecting "Dogs" from "selectFilter" dropdown, has selected value "dog" (option's text and value are different). It filters rows based on value selected and comparing it with option selected as "dog" in any row that is visible. Further filtering will not show any rows since rows were invisible based on first selection.

Comment: Its should not be like that, the filtering should be proper for each value .

Comment: What do you mean by "the filtering should be proper for each value"?

Comment: Sorry,its not what is asked for? The filter works for only one time...not for other values